# Issue while exporting a report

Tags: reporting

I am exporting a `report`(On `Opportunity`) to Excel. We have 1 decimal field (`Quantity`).

But, when I am checking the `report` in excel, the `quantity` field value is coming differently.

For Example : In `Report` is is 200, but in Excel it is coming as 200,00,000,00,000.

**in Report :**
[image]
In Excel :
[image]

Comment: is you export to CSV and open the CSV file in a text editor, what value do you see?

Comment: Also please check the format of that cell in Excel.